# Doing algebra with differential operators

Tags: variable-definitions, operators, stochastic-calculus, differentials, correlation

I'm doing some work on stochastic processes, where I use random functions which are defined by their properties over averages, i.e $$\langle f(t) \rangle =0 \\ \langle f(t) f(t')\rangle = \alpha(x,y) e^{-(t-t')^2}$$
Is there a way to define something like this?

My problem is that I have a multitude of spatial derivatives applied to those functions in different ways which I can take out of the time average i.e. $$\langle \partial_x f(t) \partial_{y'} f(t')\rangle = \partial_x \partial_{y'} \langle f(t) f(t')\rangle$$ Is there a way to just do the algebra with the operators where I could then apply a complex differential operator onto my correlation function?

Best

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with the build in D, Dt, and Derivative operators:

They execute in such a way, as if any symbolic function is differentiable in the ordinary   sense.

So if you manage to replace

```
mean[ f'[x] * g'[y]] :> D[  mean[ f[x] * g[y]],  x,y]
```

you get immediately

```
f'[x] g'[y] (mean'[f[x] g[y]]  +f[x] g[y] (f'[x] g'[y]) mean''[ f[x] g[y]]
```

None of the expressions is what you want. Conclusion: The D operator outside the mean is a strange object.

In order to suppress automatic execution while preserving the printed repesentation is an Inactive[D]

```
mean[a'[b] c'[d]] /. {mean[f_'[x_] g_'[y_]] :> Inactive[D][mean[f[x] g[y]], x, y]}
```

Observe that you cannot Activate D before its first argument is a differentiable expression or an arithmetic function with respect to the variables.

On the other hand, writing the  mean as an integral, there are no problems in exchanging integration and differentiation

```
Integrate[ w[u] D[f[x, u], x]*D[g[y,u], y],u] == D[Integrate[ w[u]f[x,u]*g[y,u], u]], x, y]

True
```